# Operator 'is true' for type 'long' not found for oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run this logic, where i get output as follows,

My code to get the below output field is shown below

```
select max(dtm) over (partition by name ,id )-current_date from mm


output
-4168
-4168
-4168
-4127
```

what i want is to run this logic along with 'case when' statement so i tried:

```
case when max(dtm) over (partition by name ,id )-current_date then 'yes'
else 'No' end as output
from mm
```

but i get an error as follows, not sure what went wrong in this logic.

```
Operator 'is true' for type 'long' not found
```

Comment: What is the condition you wanted to check? Can you please elaborate the requirement

Comment: Are you sure that the expression `max(dtm) over (partition by name ,id ) - current_date` produces a boolean result? Doesn't it return a number?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible case ? table ddl and just enough data to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: @Abra - yes it returns a number (type long).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, but i found the answer and i posted below

Comment: Is there perhaps a Java component involved? `long` is not a numeric datatype in Oracle SQL, and the error should be `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator` at the `then` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
case when current_date-max(dtm) over (partition by name ,id ) < 30 then 'yes'
else 'No' end as 'output'
from mm
```

Comment: I think that should be `as output`, not `as 'output'`.

Comment: Is this even Oracle SQL? `select 123 as 'output' from dual` gives `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`, because `'output'` is a string not a label.

Comment: Identifiers can't be quoted within single quotes in (standard) SQL and Oracle honors that

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of CASE expression. One is referred to as *simple case expression* and the other is referred to as *searched case expression*. The SQL in your question uses the latter, i.e. *searched case expression*. I believe you probably need *simple case expression*, i.e.

```sql
select case max(dtm) over (partition by name ,id ) - current_date
         when -4168 then 'Yes'
         else 'No'
       end as answer
  from mm
```